# Byte array of image into imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview

I've searched a bit but can't get a clear glimpse of it. How can I set a byte array of an Image into an `ImageView`? I tried with this but it didn't work.

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

This is how you can convert a `Bitmap` to a `ByteArray` and a `ByteArray` to a `Bitmap`:

---

Convert Bitmap to ByteArray:

```java
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Convert ByteArray to Bitmap:

```java
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), false));
```

Comment: there could be any OutOfMemoryError with this?

Comment: my image view does not show the image, Could you tell me any reasons? but there is no error

Comment: Maybe the image is too big; it refuses to paint above 2048x2048. I will edit the answer so the image is scaled when painted

Comment: you can pass the bmp Bitmap object, instead create another with createScaledBitmap method, like this: image.setImageBitmap(bmp)