# Get bitmap from byte[ ]

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera

I am making a camera app. I want to save the camera preview to SD Card. Here is the code, it saves the preview but not image only gray box.

```
mCamera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] mData, Camera mCamera) {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inMutable = true;

                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8;
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mData, 0,
                mData.length, options);

                saveImage(bitmap);
            }
        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854742/byte-array-of-image-into-imageview

Comment: Already seen, but it don't work

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromBytes(final byte[] b) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```