# How to display image from sql database to listview in android xamarin using webservices and json?

Tags: android, asp.net, xamarin

How to display image from sql database to listview in android xamarin using webservices and json?

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = objList[position];

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = objActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ContListViewHospName, null);
        }
        convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvHospID).Text = item.HospID;
        convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvHospName).Text = item.HospName;

        byte[] img = (byte[])item.HospLogo;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(item.HospLogo, 0, item.HospLogo.Length);

        convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgLogo).SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i store binary value in one string variable then i use json to transfer values to my cs file in my android project

Your store binary value in one string should looks like this: `"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFUeJzsvfd33EiW7/mJgEtHb0WKFGWqSuW96epqM9P9+s30mZ/2j33n7O7Zt/Nme8zr6emu6i5fk........"`

That is base64 bytes. You can not just use `(byte[])` to convert the `string` to `byte[]`:

you need to use `System.Convert.FromBase64String()` function.

```
//The string is download form server in the json file
string myBytes = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFUeJzsvfd33EiW7/mJgEtHb0WKFGWqS........"
byte[] decByte3 = System.Convert.FromBase64String(myBytes);
```

And then convert the bytes to image:

```
  public Bitmap Bytes2Bimap(byte[] b)
    {
        if (b.Length != 0)
        {
            return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(b, 0, b.Length);
        }
        else
        {
          return null;
        }
    }
```

and convert the bitmap to drawable :

```
Bitmap myIcon = Bytes2Bimap(decByte3);
Drawable myIconD = new BitmapDrawable(myIcon);
imageView1.Background = myIconD;
```

Comment: Thank You so much developer.. This worked for me.. This code got me an result after research of three days.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

May be your image is too big try to scale it, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13854787/5611425)

Also make sure you have set proper dimension in your layout like width and height.

Comment: my image in database is set to 100px X 100px png format, issue is when i am fetch image from database through sql server database i store binary value in one string variable then i use json to transfer values to my cs file in my android project. now in cs file when i get value of image it shows in System.Byte[] format now if i store it in byte[] variable it will allow me only if i use type cast. now when i try to convert this byte[] to bitmap to set to imageView it gives me error. this is my main issue.  Thanks in advance.