# How to convert a byte array to an image which can be displayed on an Android screen?

Tags: android, arrays, video-streaming

I have raw monochrome data in the form of a byte array (one byte per pixel).

What is the lowest-latency method of taking this data and display it as an image on-screen?

(It needs to be quick enough to display 720x480 frames as 30fps video.)

This is not a dup of [conversion of byte array to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208748/conversion-of-byte-array-to-image) and is not solved using `decodeByteArray` as this byte array contains raw data, not "byte array of compressed image data" as decodeByteArray requires.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conversion of byte array to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208748/conversion-of-byte-array-to-image)

Comment: @NileshRathod No, this byte array contains raw data, not "byte array of compressed image data" as decodeByteArray requires.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854742/byte-array-of-image-into-imageview

Comment: Try to create an empty Bitmap with the rigth resolution. Then fill in the pixels one by one. Easy to do but maybe slow.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a method involving `BitMap.createBitmap`

```
createBitmap
added in API level 1

Bitmap createBitmap (int[] colors, 
                int width, 
                int height, 
                Bitmap.Config config)

Returns a immutable bitmap with the specified width and height, with each pixel value set to the corresponding value in the colors array. Its initial density is as per getDensity(). The newly created bitmap is in the sRGB color space.
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)

Answer (score -1):

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, image.getWidth(),
                image.getHeight(), false)));

here you can set image on imageview after converting byte array to bitmap and then scaling that bitmap and setting on imageview
```

Comment: The byte array contains raw monochrome data, not the "byte array of compressed image data" which `decodeByteArray` requires.